# My VPSs CPU load hardly go beyond 0.2. Am I wasting my money on unused resources?

Tags: vps, cpu-usage

Currently, I have 5 VPSs running:

- Mail server (Zimbra)
- Database server (MySQL, PostgreSQL)
- ERP Server (OpenERP 7)
- Git Server (GoGits)
- Web Server (Apache, Nginx) with server monitoring application installed(Zabbix)

These are graphs from Server Monitoring Application (Zabbix) -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/TACbJ.jpg

Most of the VPSs are for internal use, so I don't really care about SEO, generating click/visitor or handle heavy-load traffic and there are only around 20 users using these VPSs.

From what I can see in server monitoring application, CPU of all the VPSs hardly go beyond 0.2 in 1 month period.
Which I feel like I'm paying for a resources that I don't really use.

What do you think? Should I just merge some of them together to save money or just let it be for future user growth? Or there is a better solution to make use of these CPUs.

Comment: Rather than try and "fix" something that's working fine.  Decide whether what you're spending is too much and a burden on the business.  It might be better just to stick with what's working.

Comment: Are you sure you're paying for 1.0? On many virtual hosting schemes, you are only permitted to burst to 1.0 and will find yourself brutally throttled if you stay there for long or often. (Because they've sold more vCPUs than physical CPUs.) For example, Amazon T2 instances [are like this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html). If this is a t2.small, you're maxed.

Comment: CPU is not the only resource! You need to look at everything else, too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not wasting your money.  Here's what you're getting with this setup - instant scalability, plus upgrade flexibility.

Consider the small start-up that hosts everything on one box: as they ramp up, suddenly the need to offload one of the services, but now they've got a lot more historical data to migrate, and now they're busy, both in terms of traffic and time resources.

Additionally, when you're running multiple services on a box you can get pinned down by dependencies. I.e. you want to upgrade A, but it needs a new lib B, but service C depends on the old lib B.  You can work around this, it's just a pain.

Scale back you VPSs for the moment, and when 'Christmas' comes, you'll be ready.

Comment: That presumes that will ever happen, that he wants it to happen, or that he cares it happens.

Comment: @Rob "... he cares it happens ..."?  If he's running a business, he cares, and that's the tone I read into it.  He spoke of "future grow", "save money" and is running an ERP server.  In my experience that reads like "He running a business". Perhaps not.  Fair enough. What's your take on it?

Comment: He also said, "I don't really care about SEO, generating click/visitor or handle heavy-load traffic and there are only around 20 users". Doesn't sound like much of a business, if it is one, with much growth in its future. If growth does come, then he can consolidate and expand what he has; perhaps with just a couple of clicks of the mouse nowadays.

Comment: @Rob. Thanks for taking the time to follow up.  Again, I can see your point.  Not sure I'd dedicate a whole VPS to just git either (perhaps he has other dev services on there as well?). Still looks like a biz to me though. I'll split the diff with ya, it's a nonprofit :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the advices and replies. First of all I'm not an owner of a business, I just take care of their network. Also the main website and email marketing is hosted and maintained by third party company not in theses VPSs.